# Assistance with pointers in functions to a dynamically allocated array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Im making a game about gathering elements from exoplanets. 
I would have no problem if i could do this all in one function but Im passing the pointer of an array of structs to multiple functions. So I keep getting errors because i dont know how many pointers to put the parameter and argument of each function.
 especially the function within a function (called missionMenu()) is a real headache to work with. Im also probably messing up the pointers in the function earth() too..
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I need help fixing the scanf in the missionMenu() function and i think misuse of pointers i mentioned above have something to do with it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#define flush fflush(stdin)
#define SIZE 1000


main(){

    int count=0;

    ELEMENT* element[SIZE];
    earth(&count,element);

}//End main 

void earth(int *c,ELEMENT **element){

    int userMenuChoice = 0; 
    int i;
    int number;
    displayMenu(); 

    element[*c] = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));

    scanf("%i", &userMenuChoice); 

    switch (userMenuChoice) { 
            case 1: 

                missionMenu(element[*c],*c);

                break; 
            case 2: 
                for(i=0;i<*c;i++)
                    printf("\t%i\t%i\n", element[i]->hydrogen);
                break; 
            case 3: 

                break;
    }while(userMenuChoice != 4); 

}//end end

void missionMenu(ELEMENT *element, int c ){
    int missionChoice;
    cls;

    printf("Which planet would you like to escapade/exploit? \n\n"); 
    printf("1. Gliese 436 b \n");
    printf("2. Oxygen Planet\n"); 
    printf("3. 55 Cancri E\n"); 
    printf("4. Nitrogen \n"); 
    printf("Please input your choice (1-3): \n\n"); 

    missionChoice = 0; 
    scanf("%i", &missionChoice); 
    switch (missionChoice) { 
            case 1: 

                cls;
                printf("\n\n\nWelcome to Planet Gliece 436 b, a planet made of burning ice.\n");
                printf("The extreme gravity of this planet forces the water to stay in solid form,\neven though the temperature is over 570° fahrenheit.\n\n");
                pause;




                printf("\n\n\tHow much Hydrogen would you like to collect?");
                //scanf("%i",&collect);
                scanf("%[^\n]s", element->hydrogen); flush;
                printf("\n\ntHow much Oxygen would you like to collect?");
               // scanf("%i",&collect);
                scanf("%[^\n]s", element->oxygen); flush;
                c=c+1;
                break; 
            case 2: 

                break; 
            case 3: 

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
    }while(missionChoice != 5); 
}//end mission menu



ELEMENT** newElement() {
    ELEMENT** element;
    element = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    return element;
} //end newTeam
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do i fix the pointers so that both scanf work in Mission Menu

Comment: Can you try reducing the problem to the smallest subset that expresses your issue? You've posted **a lot** of code that likely isn't relevant.  Please make this clearer in the question itself or people will vote to close it as unclear.

Comment: case in point I don't even see what pointers you are talking about and what scanf has to with your mallocs. :-)

Comment: Thanks for updating question, What specific errors are you gettting?

Comment: This seriously needs a breakdown, but as for the part you've spotted, the format string `"%[^\n]s"` would try assigning a string that is terminated with a `'\n'` to `hydrogen` and `oxygen`, and then try to obtain and discard an `'s'` character. `hydrogen` and `oxygen` aren't even character arrays that could hold a string in the first place... If you want to just store numbers inside, simply use the format string `"%d"`, along with the second argument `&element->hydrogen` and `&element->oxygen`.

Comment: There is no such thing like `switch { ... } while ( ... );`, that kind of a set-up would evaluate the `switch` statement once, and perform an empty operation, that is mentioned with the `;` (empty-statement) right after the `while` condition as long `missionChoice != 5` holds true.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin thank you! that fixed my problem with the scanf but im not sure what you are saying about the switch statement. Are you saying to just get rid of the empty statements or the whole switch?

Comment: If you are hoping to have that `switch` statement issued again and again, until `missionChoice == 5`, then rather enclose the `switch` with `while` like `while ( ... ) { switch { ... } }`, and if you want `switch` to get evaluated at least once, enclose your `switch` with a `do` like `do { switch { ... } } while ( ... );`

Comment: Okay yea that makes sense.. not sure what i was thinking. Thanks again!

Comment: `Please input your choice (1-3):` should probably be `(1-4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main` you try to call the `earth` function with a pointer to an ELEMENT, your array. If you check the definition of `earth(...)`, you see that it accepts a pointer to a pointer to an ELEMENT, which is not what you're passing it.

Comment: That is indeed what I mean

Comment: Then you should update your answer to use the correct terminology :-) That kind of edit isn't currently one I'd be able to make successfully.